# useradd with multiple parameters

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I've hit a wall after trying to find a solution to this issue. I have a file of 1000 lines from a csv that I need to use to create users within centos.

csv file is structured as username, first, last, gender, dob, country, color, fruits, OS, shell, permission

lines 601 - 1000 | Add users with the following requirements:

- username
- comment
- shell
- primary group must be their color

I have my shell script like this:

```
cat file.csv | cut -d, -f7 | tail -400 | while read group; do groupadd "$group"; done

cat file.csv | cut -d, -f1-3,7,10 | tail -400 | while read username first last color shell; do useradd "$username" -c "$first $last" -g "$color" -s "$shell"; done
```

When I run the first script, I get "groupapp: group 'color' already exists." I think mainly because it added the group the first time and when it went through the new lines, it stated it already exists. When I verify using /etc/group I do see the groups listed in there.

Now when I run the second script, I get "useradd: group ' ' does not exist". Like I stated when I looked in /etc/group the groups were there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `-g` needs a group ID, not a group name.

Answer (score 0):

For the "group already exists" problem, you could add `sort -u` into the pipeline.

For the useradd problem, see what the output of `cut` is:

```sh
$ echo '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10' | cut -d, -f1-3,7,10
1,2,3,7,10
```

To split that into separate variables with the `read` command, you need to specify that the delimiter is comma:

```sh
cut -d, -f1-3,7,10 file.csv \
| tail -400 \
| while IFS="," read -r username first last color shell; do
    useradd "$username" -c "$first $last" -g "$color" -s "$shell"
  done
```

Notes:

- `cut` can read files, don't need `cat`
- you almost always want `read -r`

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much for your explanation.